# Port regular expression from PHP to AS3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to use a regular expression from PHP in AS3 but I ran into this error:

> 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before end of program.

What do I need to change to make it work?
AS3:

```
var findTags:RegExp = / #\p{L}+\b(?!\s+\p{L})/u
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern includes a `\p` pattern that is not supported by AS3 regex engine.
Use `\\x` as per [Adobe reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea5.html) and [there is no `u` option](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea7.html).

So, try this:

```
var pattern2:RegExp = / #\\x+\b(?!\s+\\x)/gi;
```

(or maybe `var pattern2:RegExp = / #\x+\b(?!\s+\x)/gi;`, since the example is not quite clear on Adobe Web site)